# Angular2 modify constant data returned from service

Tags: angular, es6-promise

My problem:
I want to have a default data in a separate file so I can call it to reset the default value if I want to, but the Const Data get updated.

I could hardcode the value straight in the constructor, but that will block me from using the same "Blank State" across different module.

Flow:

1. Data in a **const** variable that get exported

```
    export const CONST_DATA: ConstDataStructure {
      item1: 'Basic String 1',
      item2: 'Basic String 2'
      item3: 'Basic String 3'
    }
```

2. Service that Return a Promise of that data.

```
    import { CONST_DATA } from './data.blank';
    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {
      getDefaultValue() {
        return Promise.resolve(CONST_DATA)
      }
    }
```

3. Set the Service in a **Private** item inside the Constructor.

```
    export class App implements OnInit {
      defaultData: ConstDataStructure;
      constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.resetDefaultData();
      }
      resetDefaultData() {
        this.dataService.getDefaultValue().then(data => {
          this.defaultData = data;
          console.log("Return of the Promeses should have been resseting my data to the default???");
        });
      } 
    }
```

4. But the ngModel still update the data.blank.ts (???)

**Question**: Why can the ngModel update a **Private service** that get return asynch from a **promise** that reference a **Constant**?

What is wrong and how can I fix that. See [plnk exemple here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0BeqBPdUfgrmp0aSDCqc?p=preview): for full running exemple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intresting...
I guess the problem is that your service (which is like a singleton), returns a resolved promise. this promise reference to the same object on every call which is a singleton too. your component have the same reference to that object:

```
this.defaultData = data
```

solution:
change your service to return a clone of this object:

```
export class DataService {
  getDefaultValue() {

    let data = Object.assign({}, CONST_DATA); // cloned data object
    return Promise.resolve(data);

  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, yes it work, but I feel this is more a patch than the "Angular" way of doing it.

Comment: This was only an example. as long as you understand what went wrong you can refactor your code accordingly. in your scenario all the way from the service to the component you/angular were setting new references to the same object.